# Avoid generation of final accessor methods

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am using ByteBuddy to dynamically create subclasses to add method interceptors to these classes. So far everything works, however, ByteBuddy creates `final` accessor methods for every method. When I now use ByteBuddy in combination with Spring I get a ton of messages of the form

```
[main] INFO org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to proxy method [final void com.tngtech.jgiven.integration.spring.test.proxy.GivenTestStageWithAspect$ByteBuddy$aMzxnEax.should_say_hello$accessor$7OjlyLlO()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
```

I know that I can turn down the log level in Spring. But as I am developing a library, every user of the library has to adapt the Spring log configuration which I would like to avoid. So the question is whether the generation of the accessors can be avoided or whether ByteBuddy can be configured to not make them `final`.

Comment: I know ByteBuddy just from the mockito framework. So please see https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/3 and the link provided by raphw

Comment: Why are you using ByteBuddy to add interceptors when you're using Spring? Wouldn't it be better to use [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) for that?

Comment: I am not directly using Spring as I am developing a library. The problem only occurs when the library is used in the context of a Spring application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of marking these methods to be final is to avoid them to be overridden by such proxies which would break their use from the proxy. At the same time, they are necessary as they contain `invokespecial` calls which are not allows outside of the invoking class.

In this case, I would argue that the problem lies with Spring which should not even attempt to proxy those methods for two reasons:

1. The methods are package-private; they cannot be overridden reliably even if they were not final as they are only dispatched virtually within the same class loader which is often not given for a proxy class.
2. The methods are marked as synthetic, indicating an infrastructure method which should not be touched.

I would suggest to exclude such methods by default. There is very little meaning in proxying those methods.

Comment: I already feared that you will give such an answer ;-). I completely agree that Spring should be more intelligent before printing such a warning. However, the problem is that from a library developers perspective I have no possibility to modify what the user is doing with their Spring configuration. It is a bit unsatisfying to tell the users to adapt their LOG configuration and/or Spring configuration.

Comment: I understand that and I know the frustration. I would still file the issue with Spring as many JVM languages generate synthetic accessors, its not a Byte Buddy-specific problem but rather something Spring should put up. Have you filed an issue? Excluding package-private, synthetic methods seems very reasonable.

Comment: Yes, I agree that ByteBuddy makes no mistake here. I hoped, though, that there were some way in ByteBuddy to modify the generation of the accessors so that Spring does not complain. I guess not much can be done here. Filing a bug against Spring is definitely also something I will do, but I fear that the answer will be: turn off logging ;-). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: In theory you can create a custom implementation context and register it with your byte buddy instance. If you wqnt to refactor default implementation to allow custom modifiers and send me a pr, i merge it.